# Multiplication of list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, array-broadcasting

Assume that I have a dataframe of two rows and 13 columns.
I have used df.itertuples() and formed two lists as an output

```
for row in test.itertuples(index = False):
    a = np.asarray(row)
    print(a)
```

let us assume that the Output of the above loop is

```
Output : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
[14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]
```

I have one more list which is of shape (2,)
test_y = [21,24]

I also tried

```
a = test.values.tolist()
output : array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],
[14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]])
```

this forms list of lists
and then multiplying test_y to a results in an error

```
error :operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,13) (2,)
```

The objective is multiply the list [1,2,3....] with 21 and the other with 24.
 or is there any way which is simpler than this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already converted `a` to a list, you can use `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
np.transpose(np.multiply(np.transpose(a),test_y))
```

Output:

```
[[ 21  42  63  84 105 126 147 168 189 210 231 252 273] 
 [336 360 384 408 432 456 480 504 528 552 576 600 624]]
```

If you need to sum the elements, (i.e 21+336, 42+360 and so on..) then the transpose is not required.

```
ans=np.multiply(np.transpose(a),test_y)

[[ 21 336]
 [ 42 360]
 [ 63 384]
 and so on...]
```

No just sum  each of these individual lists

```
sum_ans=[np.sum(x) for x in ans]
#[357, 402, 447, 492, 537, 582, 627, 672, 717, 762, 807, 852, 897]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Since you tag `pandas`

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['c1']= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13] 
df['c2']=[14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]
df.mul([21,24])
Out[62]: 
     c1   c2
0    21  336
1    42  360
2    63  384
3    84  408
4   105  432
5   126  456
6   147  480
7   168  504
8   189  528
9   210  552
10  231  576
11  252  600
12  273  624
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but need it in a different format

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a function to the DataFrame which calculates the multiplication:

```
In: df.apply(lambda x: x*test_y)
Out: 
    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12
0   21   42   63   84  105  126  147  168  189  210  231  252  273
1  336  360  384  408  432  456  480  504  528  552  576  600  624
```